# How to save photos from iPhone to ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, iphone

Okay so I want to transfer my iPhone photos to my laptop which is on ubuntu 16.04 than later transfer those photos to my new iPhone without iTunes back up so how do I do this?

Comment: Refer to [How can I transfer large files from Linux to iPad over a cable or wifi?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6221)

Comment: I don't get it all I want is to transfer my photos on my current phone to my laptop than transfer those photos to my new phone.